# Multiple node reference on same node

Tags: entities, nodes

In Drupal 6, I have the "Player" content type that has a field reference to the "Team" content type.
I want to make content type for sports match.

It has two referencing field for teams:

- field_host_team
- field_guest_team

I want to make a relationship for players that played, but I want the users to be able to choose only players that have a reference to the selected (home/guest) team such as:

- field_host_players (only players from team selected in field_host_team)
- field_guest_players (only players from team selected in field_guest_team)

Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a node reference for players. In node reference you can limit the list of options to a view. You can make a view that has a custom argument that looks up players from the home and away teams already attached to the node.

You might get a better answer for this, but throwing this one out there in the few mins I have.

Comment: you could also create a custom field that looks up the correct list and still uses node_reference as a formatter.